# Use the current citation counter value in Tufte-book \cite on the margin, instead of margin note numbers

Tags: bibliographies, numbering, citing, counters, tufte-book

I'm using tufte-book and I like how \cite put the reference in the margin, however I would like it to be indexed by the bibliography reference number instead that by the progressive margin notes numbers. Something like the following example.

can anyone help me?

bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
bla bl here I want to cite a reference, that is [1] bla bla......[1] Author, title,
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla........journal, year
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
bla bla bla here I put a \marginnote, giving^1  bla bla bla......1 While this is an
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla........usual margin note
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
and if I put the same citation I get the same number [1] :......[1] Author, title,
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla..........journal, year

Bibliography :

[1] Author, title, journal, year